# how to access JsonPropertyOrder

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO with `JsonPropertyOrder` defined, in other class I need to retrieve that order for that POJO, how can I do do this?

Example POJO:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"field1", "field2", "field3"})
public class ReportRow extends Row {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private String field3;
}
```

Can I try something like this: `ReportRow.getJsonPropertyOrder()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you can get annotation information for the class and then access it's properties:

```
JsonPropertyOrder jpo = ReportRow.class.getAnnotation(JsonPropertyOrder.class);
String[] propertyOrder = jpo.value();
```

In this case you can find the taget attribute in the Jackson [JsonPropertyOrder.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.java) source.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer provided, you can get to the annotation through Jackson:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(ReportRow.class);
    BeanDescription desc = mapper.getSerializationConfig().introspect(type);
    JsonPropertyOrder jpo = desc.getClassAnnotations().get(JsonPropertyOrder.class);
```

Comment: through Jackson? so this one we don't need to use the reflection package?

Comment: that's right. no reflection. although it would be nice if indeed there was `getJsonPropertyOrder()` as is suggested in the question